# What's the proper way of associating/dissociating entries in many to many relationships in REST api?

Tags: rest

I'm building a simple REST api, which is having users and communities.

`User` entity is having many to many relationship with `Community`.
User can have membership in a multiple communities and communities can have multiple users.

Endpoint for creating a user and assigning it with a specific community is the following:

```
POST /communities/5/users
```

When I want to delete a user and dissociate it with a specific community, I use this:

```
DELETE /communities/5/users/8
```

The question is, how to design the endpoint for joining a users into communities and leaving from them in a proper way(without deleting a users)?

Comment: You might want to use a third resource called `membership`. Which contains the relation between a user and a community. This allows you to do operations on the /memberships resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since users can be part of many communities or none, it would make sense to treat users as a resource independent of a community. Create them via `POST /users` and remove them from the system via `DELETE /users/:id`.

Same for communities. Create them via `POST /communities` and delete them via `DELETE /communities/:id`.

Now you can add users to a community by `POST /communities/:id/users`, where the payload contains the id of the user you want to add. You'd remove a user from the community via `DELETE communities/:id/users/:userid`.

Every community entity can have either a link to the URL for getting its users (`/communities/:id/users`) or include the users in the entity itself.

Alternatively you could have a `membership` resource to link the community and its users. This may be interesting if the membership itself has other properties than the community id and user id.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, how to design the endpoint for joining a users into communities and leaving from them in a proper way(without deleting a users)?

How would you do it with a web site?

For example: you might decide that a user gets to choose their own group membership.  So you would give the user a web page that describes the groups they belong to.  Maybe that page includes a form with a bunch of checkboxes, and the user can uncheck the boxes for the groups they don't want to belong to any more, then submit the form.

For a REST API... do the same thing.